# Checking the key in a Map

Tags: java, dictionary

Can anyone suggest me why the if condition is not working in the below code as the record has key as SiteId.

```
while (!pdsxOutRecords.isEmpty()) {
PdsxRecord record = pdsxOutRecords.remove(0);
// The below if condition is not working
if(record.getAttrs().containsKey("SiteId")) {
System.out.println("Testing");
}
}
```

And PdsxRecord class is like this

```
public class PdsxRecord
{
    private String m_key;
    private Map<PdsxAttrKey, PdsxAttrValue> m_mapAttrs;

}
// constructor
    public PdsxRecord(String key, Map<PdsxAttrKey, PdsxAttrValue> mapAttrs)
    {
        m_key = key;
        m_mapAttrs = mapAttrs;
    }

    public String getKey()
    {
        return m_key;
    }

    public Map<PdsxAttrKey, PdsxAttrValue> getAttrs()
    {
        return m_mapAttrs;
    }
```

Below thing gets printed by using `record.getAttrs()`

```
{Gem.2036=null, Gem.2037=null, Gem.2038=com.ebay.pdsx.common.PdsxAttrValue@6b306b30, Gem.2039=null, Gem.10230=null, Gem.10117=null, Gem.10119=null, Gem.10240=null, UID=com.ebay.pdsx.common.PdsxAttrValue@1e501e50, Gem.10001=null, Gem.10002=com.ebay.pdsx.common.PdsxAttrValue@5d095d09, Gem.10003=null, Gem.10246=null, Gem.10247=null, Gem.60001=null, Gem.10007=null, Gem.10009=null, GEM_ROUTING.PartnerLastModifiedDate=null, Gem.70006=null, CGUID=com.ebay.pdsx.common.PdsxAttrValue@1e361e36, Gem.10173=null, Gem.10097=null, Gem.10131=null, Gem.10010=null, Gem.10132=null, Gem.10177=null, Gem.10178=null, Gem.10179=null, Gem.10015=null, TimeStamp=com.ebay.pdsx.common.PdsxAttrValue@1e571e57, Gem.10016=com.ebay.pdsx.common.PdsxAttrValue@645e645e, Gem.10018=null, Gem.10019=null, Gem.2025=null, SiteId=com.ebay.pdsx.common.PdsxAttrValue@1e3f1e3f, GEM_ROUTING.Partner1LastLoggedInUserId=null, GEM_ROUTING.Partner3LastLoggedInUserId=null, Gem.10181=null, Gem.10182=null, Gem.10183=null, Gem.10185=null, Gem.10187=null, Gem.10101=null, Gem.10189=null, Gem.10102=null, Gem.10026=null, PGuid=com.ebay.pdsx.common.PdsxAttrValue@1e461e46, Gem.2032=null, SGuid=null, Gem.2033=null, Gem.2034=null, Gem.2035=null}
```

This is the below PdsxRecord class

```
    public class PdsxRecord
{
    private String m_key;
    private Map<PdsxAttrKey, PdsxAttrValue> m_mapAttrs;

    // use the other constructor!
    protected PdsxRecord()
    {
    }

    // constructor
    public PdsxRecord(String key, Map<PdsxAttrKey, PdsxAttrValue> mapAttrs)
    {
        m_key = key;
        m_mapAttrs = mapAttrs;
    }

    /**
     * get Key 
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public String getKey()
    {
        return m_key;
    }

    /**
     * get attributes as a map of key=value
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public Map<PdsxAttrKey, PdsxAttrValue> getAttrs()
    {
        return m_mapAttrs;
    }

    /**
     * String -- for debugging and simple persistence
     */
    public String toString()
    {
        UnsynchronizedStringBuffer buf = new UnsynchronizedStringBuffer();
        buf.append("key=" + getKey() + "\n");
        if (getAttrs() == null || getAttrs().size() == 0) {
            return buf.toString();
        }

        for (Map.Entry<PdsxAttrKey, PdsxAttrValue> entry : getAttrs().entrySet()) {
            String key = (entry.getKey()==null ? "null" : entry.getKey().getKey());
            String value = ((entry.getValue() == null ||
                            entry.getValue().getValue() == null) ? 
                        "null" : entry.getValue().getValue().toString());
            buf.append("  " + key + "=" + value +"\n");
        }
        return buf.toString();
    }

}
```

Updated:- Class for PdsxAttrKey

```
public class PdsxAttrKey
    {
        private String m_key;

        protected PdsxAttrKey()
        {
        }

        public PdsxAttrKey(String key)
        {
            m_key = key;
        }

        public String getKey()
        {
            return m_key;
        }

        /**
         * Override the default to allow comparing with Strings 
         */
        public boolean equals(Object o)
        {
            if (o == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (o instanceof String) {
                return o.equals(m_key);
            }
            if (o instanceof PdsxAttrKey) {
                return m_key.equals(((PdsxAttrKey)o).getKey());
            }
            return false;
        }

        /**
         * hash code implementation
         */
        public int hashCode()
        {
            return (m_key == null ? 0 : m_key.hashCode());
        }

        public String toString()
        {
            return getKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the question?  Please explain more clearly, and show what you are expecting and what you are actually getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe because you Map is consisting of `PdsxAttrKey` as a key, and you are checking if there's a key which is a `String` with value "SiteId".

Here's some code that might be useful if you do not want to change your Map definition from `Map<PdsxAttrKey, PdsxAttrValue>` to something like `Map<String, PdsxAttrValue>`:

```
while (!pdsxOutRecords.isEmpty()) {
  PdsxRecord record = pdsxOutRecords.remove(0);
  if(record.getAttrs().containsKey(new PdsxAttrKey("SiteId"))) {
    System.out.println("Testing");
  }
}
```

Note that this assumes that you can pass a String to the PdsxAttrKey constructor, and that the class can be instantiated. Oh and of course that you have `equals()` and `hashcode()` in  the class, which pretty much only check the String value for the of the `PdsxAttrKey`. You might ask yourself if this is really worth the hassle. That's why I originally suggested that your change your Map definition to use Strings as keys, but of course I am not sure if this is a viable solution in your case.

Comment: So how can I check that as a `PdsxAttrKey` ? Any idea?

Comment: If you do not need any other functionality than a String then I say change your Map definition. That's for one. Otherwise instead of checking for a `String` create a `PdsxAttrKey` which has the value "siteId" and make sure your `PdsxAttrKey` class has a `equals()` method

Comment: We can't tell without knowing the `PdsxAttrKey` class. If you are lucky, it can be constructed by a `String` and it implements `equals()` and `hashcode()` appropriately.

Comment: I have edited my question by posting full PdsxRecord class. Let me know if that is helpful to you and if I can use the code you posted by seeing that class?

Comment: If you want to lookup by a `String`, then it should be a `Map<String, Value>`.

Comment: Actually I am woking on someone else code, And I cannot change the datastructure, I have to work on the same datastructure, So what can be the best way to do this?

Comment: @Nevzz03: in that case we need to see the code for the pdsxAttrKey class. See, the problem here (in your code) is that you are checking if an apple and a pear is equivalent, which of course doesn't work since the JVM doesn't know how to do that.

Comment: @posdef, I have updated my question with pdsxAttrKey class. Let me know if that is helpful to you.

Comment: Did you try the while loop I gave above, if so what happens?

Answer (score 2):

In `record.getAttrs()` you're returning: `Map<PdsxAttrKey, PdsxAttrValue>`. Then you checking if there is a key (type: `PdsxAttrKey`) of type `String`, value "SiteId".

You should check if map contains `PdsxAttrKey` (implementing `equals` and `hashcode` methods in `PdsxAttrKey`) or extracting keys from `PdsxAttrKey` and comparing them with "SiteId".

If you choose to iterate try this:

```
            for(PdsxAttrKey key : record.getAttrs().keySet()) {
                if("SiteId".equals(key.getYourKeyStringValue())) {
                    //found
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Otherwise you should implement `equals` and `hashcode` (remember - both) in `PdsxAttrKey` and invoke `contains`:

```
            PdsxAttrKey lookupKey = new PdsxAttrKey("SiteId"); //with consideration of `equals` method
            if(record.getAttrs().containsKey(lookupKey)) {
                ...
            }
```

Comment: So how can I check that as a `PdsxAttrKey` ? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

As Xeon says, if you want to compare object with string value, you must override `equals` and `hascode` method in the class which is used as key, in this case, `PdsxAttrKey`. As an example:

```
public class PdsxAttrKey {
    public String name; 

    public PdsxAttrKey(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return name.hashCode(); 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj == null) {
            return false;
        } else if (obj instanceof PdsxAttrKey) {
            return this.name.equals(((PdsxAttrKey)obj).name);
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

Or If there is no real need to have an object as key, then you can redefine the map declaration as follows and use strings as key.

`private Map<String, PdsxAttrValue> m_mapAttrs;`